# Geoserver SLD for min-max scale range display

Tags: geoserver, sld, scale

I am new to GeoServer.

I am trying to add a scale range to a layer that I am serving as a WMS. I want the layer to only be displayed between 1:30,000 and 1:1,000,000. I am using the max/min scale denominators in the SLD but am not having much luck. It works if I have just one scale denominator, but not if I introduce a second one to create a range.

Current SLD below:

```
      <NamedLayer>
<Name>grid</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1000000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>300000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e32222</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

This code currently does the reverse of what I am trying to achieve. The layer is displayed beyond the two scales not between them.

Comment: For defining a range minimum must be smaller than maximum. I believe you will enjoy reading the SLD cookbook. Start from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html#zoom-based-polygon.

Comment: If I try to use a single rule I get a validation error.

Comment: If I download http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/polygon_zoombasedpolygon.sld and put it into the Style editor window in GeoServer 2.7.1 it validates for me. You say that for you it does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below SLD code works for scale range:

```
       <NamedLayer>
<Name>grid</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <MinScaleDenominator>300000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>1000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```